# Flutter Error when changing DropDownButton Selection

Tags: flutter, dart

Error:

```
Failed assertion: line 609 pos 15: 'items == null ||
        I/flutter (24295): items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value ==
        I/flutter (24295): value).length == 1': is not true.
```

I did some research and did not figure out what caused the problem. Here is my code:

```
class StatusList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StatusListState createState() => _StatusListState();
}

class _DispositionListState extends State<DispositionList> {

  var _currentSelectedValue = '';

  Future<RecordList> recordList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    recordList = getRecord();
    super.initState();
  }

  int i = 1;
  List<String> statusList = List<String>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<RecordList>(
        future: recordList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            String current = snapshot.data.record[0].status.trim();
            statusList.add(snapshot.data.record[0].status.trim());

            while (i < snapshot.data.record.length) {
              if (snapshot.data.record[i].status.trim() != current) {
                statusList.add(snapshot.data.record[i].status.trim());
                current = snapshot.data.record[i].status.trim();
              }
              i++;
            }
            _currentSelectedValue = statusList[0]; //not set this will straight getting error

            return DropdownButton(
              items: statusList.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: dropDownStringItem,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 200.0,
                      child: Text(
                        dropDownStringItem,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ));
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String valueSelected) {
                onDropDownSelected(valueSelected);
              },
              value: _currentSelectedValue,
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }

  void onDropDownSelected(String valueSelected) {
    setState(() {
      this._currentSelectedValue = valueSelected;
    });
  }
}
```

I tried compare the recordList and the valueSelected in onDropDownSelected return true. Problem caused when the setState is called even without any code inside. Anyone idea of what caused the problem based on these code?

> Added code: Here is my getRecord()

```
Future<RecordList> getRecord() async {
  String url = 'some url';
  final response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return RecordList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

class Record {
  final String status;
  final String disposition;
  final int total;

  Record({this.status, this.disposition, this.total});

  factory Record.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Record(
        status: json['status'],
        disposition: json['disposition'],
        total: json['total']);
  }
}

class RecordList {
  final List<Record> record;

  RecordList({this.record});

  factory RecordList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Record> record = new List<Record>();
    record = parsedJson.map((i) => Record.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return new RecordList(
      record: record,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be that the `value` property of `DropdownButton` has the value which is not one of `item`'s value. `value` property should be either `null` or one of the item's value.

Also, maybe you don't need a `FutureBuilder` here. You can do something like that:

```dart
class _DispositionListState extends State<DispositionList> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  String _currentSelectedValue;
  List<String> statusList = List<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadStatusList();
  }

  _loadStatusList() async {
    final recordList = await getRecord();
    final list = recordList.record.map((r) { 
      return r.status.trim();
    }).toSet().toList();
    setState(() {
      statusList = list;
      _currentSelectedValue = list.first;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : _buildDropdown();
  }

  Widget _buildDropdown() {
    return DropdownButton(
      items: statusList.map((dropDownStringItem) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: dropDownStringItem,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200.0,
            child: Text(
              dropDownStringItem,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (valueSelected) {
        onDropDownSelected(valueSelected);
      },
      value: _currentSelectedValue,
    );
  }

  void onDropDownSelected(String valueSelected) {
    setState(() {
      this._currentSelectedValue = valueSelected;
    });
  }
}
```

> Update: Added `.toSet()` to filter out duplicates from `statusList`

I think the problem is that the status list has duplicated items. I added `.toSet()` before `.toList()` to filter out duplicates. `Set` is a collection of objects in which each object can occur only once.

Comment: Tried your code, the problem still exist. I also added getRecord() code in my question.

Comment: Do you know why my original code will add the first item to the list whenever I click the selection instead of display the selected value? This is the cause of error for my original code.

Comment: Because of you never reset `statusList` value. So every time `builder` is called, it adds values to `statusList`.